# OpenCV: Image size increases after compressed

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, image-compression

I am trying to compare the size of a bunch of images before and after compression using the `quality=90` argument of OpenCV. But before compression, I want to crop all of them to a fixed size. I don't understand, however, why the average size of images after crop is smaller than after crop+compression?

Here is what I'm doing:

```py
import cv2
import PIL
from pathlib import Path

image_paths = [...]

cropped_imgs_size = 0
compressed_imgs_size = 0

# crop images
for orig_img_path in image_paths:
    cropped_img_path = "cropped_" + orig_img_path
    PIL.Image.open(orig_img_path).crop((0,0,256,256)).convert('RGB').save(cropped_img_path)
    cropped_imgs_size += Path(cropped_img_path).stat().st_size

    # compress cropped image
    dest_path = "q90_" + cropped_img_path
    cv2.imwrite(dest_path, cv2.imread(cropped_img_path), [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90])
    compressed_imgs_size += Path(dest_path).stat().st_size
```

- Expected: `compressed_imgs_size < copped_imgs_size`
- Actual: `compressed_imgs_size > copped_imgs_size`

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you attach a sample input image and the crop coordinates as well? Also what is the actual difference in file sizes?

Comment: I'm using Oxford pets dataset as `image_paths`. Average size of cropped images is ~14KB and compressed size is ~20KB with the above code. Shared other metrics at https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_RjdPwEjsgi9MmfHb5CxvvRBEnogcnOG#scrollTo=g8aAlwZfeH3j

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you are saving the crop using `PIL.save()`. As you can see on the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg), the default `quality=75`:

> The [`save()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save) method supports the following options:
>
> - **quality**: the image quality, on a scale from 1 (worst) to 95 (best). The **default is 75**. Values above 95 should be avoided; 100 disables portions of the JPEG compression algorithm, and results in large files with hardly any gain in image quality.
> - ...

Then, you use `cv2.imwrite()` passing `quality=90`. Therefore, what you get is the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks Berriel. So you recommend I change to `PIL.Image.open(orig_img_path).crop((0,0,256,256)).convert('RGB').save(cropped_img_path, quality=90)` for cropping?

Comment: Also do `PIL` and `cv2` use the same quantization tables? I'm just concerned if there are any side effects of using two libraries.

Comment: @Nitin The quality you will save your crop is basically your decision. I don't know your requirements. Anyway, I would recommend you to stick to one library only; less problems, definitely. If this answers your question, consider marking as answer :)

Comment: Basically I want the `crop` function to just crop and not change the quality. Then I want to compare it with compress in a later step. To achieve this is it reasonable to set `quality=100` during crop then?

Comment: @Nitin I think it is more reasonable to save in uncompressed format, such as PNG.

Comment: Looks like imagemagick does a lossless crop as well and I verified it [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_RjdPwEjsgi9MmfHb5CxvvRBEnogcnOG#scrollTo=DJVSadW71RTQ&line=3&uniqifier=1). Thanks to this [comment](https://github.com/google/guetzli/issues/195#issuecomment-514309053)